# Open Source Ad/Banner System in PHP?

Tags: php, open-source, banner

My client needs to have a banner management system installed to their site.
They want the system to be able to manage banners based on time (i.e. a client purchases an ad for 3 months, the site needs to not display that ad after 3 months time even if we don't change any settings)
It also needs to integrate into our website.  We have the client information already saved to our database, we want an ad system that can link up with our existing client database if possible.
Are there any php solutions available like this?

Comment: This is not programming related. While you are asking for a solution based on PHP, you are not asking a question _about_ PHP. You are looking for a software recommendation. This should be migrated to superuser.

Comment: @tinkertim: Its related to coding and not to using any program so its wise to be in stack

Comment: No, he wants an open-source banner management app *written* in PHP; he isn't asking how he'd go about making one.

Comment: @BraedenP: yep.. AFAICU he doesn't want finished product for consumer.. he is asking for library that he can use in his program to manage advertisements for the website, so where superuser comes into play ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had good experience with [phpAdsNew](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpadsnew/).

Comment: yep, thats the one. OpenX sucks, sry, it does.